# Adding a listener after a file has been selected for upload

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails-3

I am using rails file_field tag to upload a file as follows:

```
<%= f.file_field :image, :class => 'file_field' %>
```

Using some css work arounds I created a button to upload a file (the whole thing is clickable):

[image]

After the user clicks on the button and chooses a file, I would like to give the user some indication that a file has been selected for upload before the user submits the form. Otherwise, the user will have no idea that a file has been selected.

What method could I use (whether it be within Rails or a Javascript event handler) that would allow me to give the user such an indication?

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick.  It's in jQuery, but converting it to use straight javascript isn't too difficult

First: Some HTML with a file input:

```
<div>
  Click to upload a file. <input type="file" id="fileUploader" />
  <br />
  <span id="fileName"><em>No File Chosen Yet</em></span>
</div>
```

Now the javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

//bind to change event to determine when user chooses a file to upload
$("#fileUploader").bind("change", function (e)
{
    //get the file path
    var file = $("#fileUploader").val();

    //pull out the filename
    file = file.replace(/^.*\\/i, "");

    //show to user
    $("#fileName").html("You chose: " + file);
});

</script>
```